# How to determine the maximum value between trades

Tags: excel, vba

I have a stock trading spreadsheet and I would like to determine the maximum value and minimal value between trades. The spreadsheet looks something like this:

```
**Date**     **Stock  **Price**   **Action** **TradeNumber**
01/01/2018   Apple    1000.00           Buy    1
02/01/2018   Apple      995.25          -
03/01/2018   Apple      992.50          -
04/01/2018   Apple      987.50          -
05/01/2018   Apple      965.00         Close  1
```

I have a Range for the Column that contains the trade numbers. I would like to cycle through this range and each time I come across a Cell with a trade number, I need to determine the maximum value of the Price Column for the period that I held the Apples shares. I am struggling the work out the range of the cells for the maximum formula, =Max(C2:C5:). Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does it have to be in vba? you could do what you want by adding columns with vlookups for a given `Stock`, then do the `max()` of those...or something similar. Its easy in vba as well though

Comment: Will the trade numbers be unique?  I take it on 06/01/2018 or some later date you could quite possibly buy apples again?  Will there be any other stock intermingled with the apples or will it always go _Buy.... Close_ with no other stock inbetween?

Comment: Hi Darren,  A good question. The spread sheet is just for trading Apple stock. The trade numbers follow sequentially . I buy the stock and close out the trade at a later date. I also sell the stock and close out the trade at a later date. I am trying to work out the maximum stock price of Apple during the period that the trade is in progress.  Any questions, let me.

Comment: Glad you've got your answer.  If you put my @ followed by my user name I'll get a notification when you reply in comments.  @LawrenceHorner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach via dictionary**

Suggest to get data via a datafield array and to use a **dictionary** where I log the *unique trade numbers* as **key** and the referring array indices together with the *maximum price value* as items.

Furthermore I assume

- your data range includes a **title row**
- your **date** range to calculate the *minimum/maximum price* **includes** as well the *buy date* as the *closing date* (*sure you can change these values easily if not so*).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub Stock()
  Const colTrdNo As Integer = 5     ' column of TradeNo, e.g. 5th column
  Dim sTrdNo As String, sTrdNoOld As String
  Dim v, vKeys, vItems
  Dim i      As Long, n As Long
  Dim dHigh  As Double
  Dim dict   As Object              ' late bound dictionary
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim ws     As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Apple")   ' << change to your sheet name
' -----------------------
' I.  Get data
' -----------------------
' get last row in range
  n = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' get data from column A:E to variant 1-based 2-dim datafield array
  v = ws.Range("A1:E" & n)
' ------------------------
' II. Use dictionary
' ------------------------
' check price when closing
  For i = 2 To UBound(v)                    ' << assume you omit title row
      sTrdNo = v(i, colTrdNo)
      If dict.exists(sTrdNo) Then           ' Close
         dict(sTrdNo) = dict(sTrdNo) & "," & i
         dict(sTrdNo) = dict(sTrdNo) & " => Min/Max $ " & getMinMax(v, dict(sTrdNo))
      ElseIf Len(sTrdNo) = 0 Then           ' do nothing (don't change ElseIf ORDER!)
      Else                                  ' new TradNo -> Buy
         dict.Add sTrdNo, i
      End If
  Next i
' ------------------------
' III. Get needed info
' ------------------------
    Debug.Print String(30, "~")
    vKeys = dict.keys()
    vItems = dict.items()
    For i = LBound(vKeys) To UBound(vKeys)
        Debug.Print i & " TradeNo " & vKeys(i) & ": Items " & vItems(i)
    Next i
' clear memory
  Set dict = Nothing
  Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Helper function**

```
Function getMinMax(arr, ByVal s As String) As String
' Purpose: calculate highest price in array (given items range s)
Const colPRICE As Integer = 3
Dim i As Long, iStart As Long, iLast As Long
Dim dHigh As Double, dLow As Double
iStart = Val(Split(s, ",")(0)): iLast = Val(Split(s & ",", ",")(1))
dLow = 99999999999#
For i = iStart To iLast
    If arr(i, colPRICE) > dHigh Then dHigh = arr(i, colPRICE)
    If arr(i, colPRICE) < dLow Then dLow = arr(i, colPRICE)
Next i
getMinMax = dLow & " - " & dHigh
End Function
```